# Export suite from Selenium IDE produces xxx.spec.js file with "waitForWindow(2000)" that blows up

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am recording my tests using the Selenium IDE and then exporting to javascript mocha. I have installed selenium-webdriver, mocha, and nodejs.

When I run the exported file dealer.spec.js, my first 3 tests pass but the 4th one fails. I have tracked it down to when I click the FaceBook link. The error that I am receiving in the command prompt is:

1. Dealer
   Dealership Overview:
   ReferenceError: waitForWindow is not defined
   at Context. (dealer.spec.js:68:23)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Here is a snippit of the offending code:

```js
vars["root"] = await driver.getWindowHandle()
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["root"])
    vars["windowHandles"] = await driver.getAllWindowHandles()
    await driver.findElement(By.id("FacebookLogo")).click()
    vars["win4361"] = await waitForWindow(2000)
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["win4361"])
    vars["fbURL"] = await driver.executeScript("return window.location.href.substring(0,24);")
    assert(vars["fbURL"].toString() == "https://www.facebook.com")
    await driver.close()
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["root"])
    vars["windowHandles"] = await driver.getAllWindowHandles()
    await driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_TwitterLogo")).click()
    vars["win5590"] = await waitForWindow(2000)
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["win5590"])
    vars["twitterURL"] = await driver.executeScript("return window.location.href.substring(0,19);")
    assert(vars["twitterURL"].toString() == "https://twitter.com")
    await driver.close()
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["root"])
    vars["windowHandles"] = await driver.getAllWindowHandles()
    await driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_LinkedInLogo")).click()
    vars["win877"] = await waitForWindow(2000)
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["win877"])
    vars["LinkedinURL"] = await driver.executeScript("return window.location.href.substring(0,24);")
    assert(vars["LinkedinURL"].toString() == "https://www.linkedin.com")
    await driver.close()
    await driver.switchTo().window(vars["root"])
```

I see that this is a function but is not defined. Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Is waitForWindows definied in your code?

Comment: It is not...the thing the surprises me is that the code runs fine in the IDE, you would expect that the javascript that it exports would work fine as well. Also, if I run the .side files using selenium-side-runner, that are created in the IDE, those run fine.